# net-snmp TUT:Writing a MIB Module doesn't work

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I just follow the net-snmp tutorial step by step, I really can't get the right result.
here is the link
[HERE](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/TUT:Writing_a_MIB_Module)

I'm facing the same problem, I even didn't pass the tutorial.

here are my details:
my configure command:

```
./configure --with-default-snmp-version="3" --with-sys-contact="@@no.where" --with-sys-location="Unknown" --with-logfile="/var/log/snmpd.log" --with-persistent-directory="/var/net-snmp" --with-mib-modules="nstAgentModuleObject"
```

after configuration:
part of the ./configure output

```
checking for and configuring mib modules to use...  nstAgentModuleObject default_modules.
 nstAgentModuleObject default_modules snmpv3mibs mibII ucd_snmp notification notification-log-mib target agent_mibs agentx dism
```

and after all:

```
---------------------------------------------------------
            Net-SNMP configuration summary:
---------------------------------------------------------

  SNMP Versions Supported:    1 2c 3
  Building for:               linux
  Net-SNMP Version:           5.7.2.1
  Network transport support:  Callback Unix Alias TCP UDP IPv4Base SocketBase TCPBase UDPIPv4Base UDPBase
  SNMPv3 Security Modules:     usm
  Agent MIB code:             nstAgentModuleObject default_modules =>  snmpv3mibs mibII ucd_snmp notification notification-log-mib target agent_mibs agentx disman/event disman/schedule utilities host
  MYSQL Trap Logging:         unavailable
  Embedded Perl support:      enabled
  SNMP Perl modules:          building -- embeddable
  SNMP Python modules:        disabled
  Crypto support from:        internal
  Authentication support:     MD5 SHA1
  Encryption support:         DES AES
  Local DNSSEC validation:    disabled
```

I used nm to check whether the function has been compiled into the library.

```
akamai@JNdev:~/Workspace/net-snmp-5.7.2.1/net-snmp-5.7.2.1/agent/.libs$ nm libnetsnmpmibs.so | grep init_nst
00000000000331c0 T init_nstAgentModuleObject
```

Comment: Are you actually writing a MIB module, or are you just trying to compile the nstAgentModuleObject.h and nstAgentModuleObject.c from the tutorial? If the latter, maybe report this to the net-snmp-users mailing list, as a possible bug in the document?

Comment: Hi Jolta: I just followed the official tutorial to insert an additional OID into the agent, I also tried to add a subagent, but neither of them works. I'm using Ubuntu 14 (server), and net-snmp package 5.7 and 5.6. My work is to add some OIDs to monitor some devices. Do you know is this a bug or did I miss something? What kind of snmp package did you use before? Thank you.

Comment: Hi Jolta, do you know some simpler way to add or change OID? I just need to use that to check my ARM board GPIO status. IF there are some other ways to do that, it will be ok for me. I have stuck here for around two weeks, I found online someone said there's a bug, but I'm not sure that's for Ubuntu 14 Server or ARM debian(ARMv7).

Comment: Did you try contacting the net-snmp-users mailing list?

Comment: Hi Jolta, at last I gave up, now I will use the email to report the status rather than net-snmp, I spent two weeks on snmp, only tried to implement so simple function. I didn't see any sense to use net-snmp.

Comment: @Jolta, it works this week, soooooo weird, for no reason, it just works now, I have repeated for hundreds of times in two weeks. I don't know why it's working now. But now I have another problem, few people nowadays are using net-snmp, so if you have some time, could you have a glance on   [snmp enterprise OID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24685135/snmpwalk-no-results-for-enterprisemyself-oid-oid-when-snmpd-conf-include-it)